# SpriteKit has constraints?

Tags: sprite-kit

In a game scene it’s not like the normal ui view which you can put constraints so in any iOS device it would be the same.

So how can make it in a game scene?

Is there also constraints or something similar?

It would really help if you see my code.

Comment: Most games in sprite kit are designed to be made for 1 virtual screen size (your scene size)  and you use scaling to determine asset placement.  If it is imperative to use constraints, you should subview a UIView and lay it over your SKScene

Comment: How to use scaling? Is by doing frame.size.height/width or it’s default

Comment: No it is built in with .scaleMode.

Comment: i get this error Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'graphs' and "entities' why?